# Network access to KVM adapter

Tags: keyboard-video-mouse

I have a one end of a Fujitsu-Siemens KVM S2-Adapter PS/2 VGA connected to the local network and the ps2/vga to a server. I am wondering how I can establish a connection to this adapter or if I need to hook it up to a KVM switch to be able to access the server through the network. I would like to be able to access the BIOS of the server through the network.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a device like the following you will need to connect it to a real KVM switch as it is just the console adapter. It will connect with a standard Cat5 cable to the switch but this can't (and shouldn't) be connected to a LAN - it's not a network device at all.

[image]

Comment: So in order to make this servers bios available to any client on the network I need to connect this to a kvm switch, which I then put into the network, correct?

Comment: Yes, but you need to buy a KVM switch which is compatible with this adapter and has KVMoIP functionality - not all do. In the future, make sure to only buy servers that have this functionality built in (it's available for most server models today, but sometime is an add on feature you have to buy an additional license for).

Comment: DSR2161 Avocent 16 Port KVM over IP Switch
Something like this then?

Comment: Something like this. I've no idea if those modules are compatible. That's something you need to check yourself.